# What to do with extra prosessor with Windows 8.1 (non-professional)?

Tags: windows, windows-8, cpu, multi-threaded

My desktop workstation has two quad core processors.  I recently installed Windows 8.1, and I found that without the Professional version of Windows 8 you can only use one socket here:

[How many physical processors does Windows 8 Support?](https://superuser.com/questions/495105/how-many-physical-processors-does-windows-8-support)

So I have a full quad-core CPU that is completely unused, but I don't want to buy a professional license...

So my question is: does any one know of something that I can do with this processor?  Can I use it for something else while I am running Windows?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one example of how you can make use of both CPUs:

- Install a free bare-metal [hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) ([VMware vSphere Hypervisor](http://www.vmware.com/ca/en/products/vsphere-hypervisor/), [MS Hyper-V Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/dn205299.aspx), or [Linux running KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) for example).
- Create a VM and install your Windows 8.1.
- Create one or more other VM's, and install a free OS like Linux.
- Run more than one VM at a time.
- Do whatever you want in which ever VM(s) you'd like to put load on. :)

The hypervisor will use both CPUs to provide resources for the VMs.